# Oracle to mysql conversion

Tags: mysql, oracle

how do i convert from oracle to sql?

any difference putting (+) on the left or (+) right side?

can assist convert it for me, trying online tools doesnt work for me.

```
SELECT sc.serial_no, sc.status, ca2.cust_ref_no, ca2.name, ca2.msis, ca2.state_name, to_char(ca2.term_datetime,'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI AM') te_datetime, ca2.serial_no term_ssno 
from so sc,  
( select ca.so_id, c.cust_ref_no, c.name, ca.msis, s.state_name, ca.te_datetime, t.serial_no 
from customer c, customer_account ca, state s, terminal t 
where c.install_state_id= s.state_id and c.cust_id = ca.cust_id and ca.term_id = t.term_id(+)) ca2 
where sc.so_id=ca2.so_id (+)and sc.status='Term'
```

Comment: If you have only one query, IMO you should better convert it manually. For plus sign, search using google with keyword `join with plus sign oracle` to understand it and change to `LEFT JOIN` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Using (+) is sql-92 standard and it is highly recommended to use ANSI standard.

(+) indicates the nature of the join LEFT or RIGHT join.

For your query, It will go like this:

```
SELECT sc.serial_no, sc.status, 
       ca2.cust_ref_no, ca2.name, 
       ca2.msis, ca2.state_name, 
       to_char(ca2.term_datetime,'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI AM') te_datetime, 
       ca2.serial_no term_ssno 
from so sc LEFT JOIN  
( select ca.so_id, c.cust_ref_no, 
         c.name, ca.msis, 
         s.state_name, ca.te_datetime, t.serial_no 
from customer c 
JOIN customer_account ca ON c.cust_id = ca.cust_id
JOIN state s ON c.install_state_id= s.state_id
LEFT JOIN terminal t ON ca.term_id = t.term_id) ca2 
ON sc.so_id=ca2.so_id
WHERE sc.status='Term'
```